# .htaccess Redirecting All Errors to a PHP file with GET variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect all errors pages to redirect to`/error.php?e={ERROR HERE}`.

For example, if the user encountered a 404 error, they will be directed to `/error.php?e=404`.

Is there a possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache error document config. Here is the more info

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we would just be able to do:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
```

However, if the original URL has a query string, it will override any set in the ErrorDocument (I believe).  A solution could be to use a combination of `ErrorDocument` and a `RewriteRule`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /error.php?e=$1 [L]
```

`ErrorDocument` sets up the default page that's returned for the various errors.  The `RewriteRule` sends the request to the actual php file, and passes the number in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

A more advanced approach would be to use the custom REDIRECT_ variables Apache creates for you. Refer to this awesome blog post to know more about the environment variable to customize your ErrorDocument 
http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2017/01/custom-apache-error-handler-error-url-php/

You might also wanna go over the Apache Documentation on Custom Error Pages at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html